# PHP POST data not displaying

Tags: php, database, sqlite, http-post

Im having some Trouble getting a simple PHP Login form to pass and check Login Data against a Database. For some reason the Data will not pass across from the Html Form to the PHP handler. Both are separate files but the code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1> Welcome please Login: </h1>
   <form action="LoginCreate.php" method="post">
       Username: <input type=“name” name=“username” id="username"><br/>
       Password: <input type="password” name=“password” id="password"><br/>
       <input type="submit" value="Login"> <input type="submit" value="Create Account">
    </form>
```

Then for the PHP fike: (please note I have not yet added code for checking against the database.)

```
<?
$db=sqlite_open("database.db");

$username = sqlite_escape_string($_POST["username"]);

$password = sqlite_escape_string($_POST["password"]);

if(isset($_POST['Create Account'])){

sqlite_query($db,"INSERT INTO username (name) VALUES ('$username')");
sqlite_query($db,"INSERT INTO password (password) VALUES ('$password')");

echo "<p> Account Created. <p>";

}
else if(isset($_POST['Login'])){

echo "<p> Login Successful. <p>";

}

sqlite_close($db);
?>
```

What should be causing the Data not to be Posting correctly, have I got the syntax wrong somewhere? I'm using MicroApache and getting no Errors popup in Chrome.

Comment: Well, you have a `type`-declaration on username that doesn't exist - not saying it's the problem, but it should be `text`, not `name`.

Comment: try print_r($_POST); and see if anything displays, help you narrow it down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `name="action"` attribute to your submit buttons and check

```
if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    if ($_POST['action'] == 'Create Account') {

    } elseif ($_POST['action'] == 'Login') {

    }
}
```

Comment: This gives me an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IS_EQUAL, expecting ',' or ')' in C:\wwwroot\Assignment2\LoginCreate.php on line 8

Comment: Fixed the example